# Verify that I found an example of a degenerate random variable that is not constant on the probability space

Tags: probability, solution-verification, self-learning

Let $\Omega = \{3,4\}$ be a sample space.  Define a probability measure $P$ on $\Omega$ by $P[3] = 0$ and $P[4] = 1$.

Let $X$ be the random variable defined by $X(\omega) = \omega$.

Definition: A random variable $X$ is *degenerate* if there is some real number $b$ such that $P[X = b] = 1$.

I claim that my random variable $X$ above is an example of a degenerate random variable that is not a constant function on all of $\Omega$ since $X(3) \neq X(4)$.

Am I right?

I'm self-studying from an undergraduate intro to probability textbook and this problem asks to come up with such an example.  It's from the very first chapter.

Comment: Your example is correct.

Comment: @geetha290krm Thanks.  I second guessed myself because I find it strange to include $3$ as an outcome yet it has probability $0$ of occurring.  I can't think of an experiment I guess with such a scenario so I just stuck with the mathematical definition of a probability space when thinking up an example.  Not enough experience yet.

Comment: For all practical reasons $X\equiv 4$ $P$-a.s. that is, $X$ is a constant in the eyes of the law $P$.

Comment: @Mittens I do not understand your comment.

Comment: @E2R0NS: consider the uniform distribution on $[0,1]$ and let $X=\mathbb{1}_{[0,1]\setminus \mathbb{Q}}$. $X$ is a degenerate random variable and it is not constant. However, in integration, sets of measure theory do not make any difference.  $X=1$ almost surely and one might as well work with the constant function $X=1$ if the uniform distribution is what governs the nature of our problem.